# Receive data from Adapter to DetailsActivity?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to know how I can receive the data from adapter (recyclerview) to DetailsActivity. I tried many times but the images from recyclerview doesn't show in DetailsActivity.
this is my code.

**ImageAdapter**

```
class ImageAdapter (private var items:List<Item>, private val context:Context):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):ViewHolder {
   return ViewHolder(
       LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
   )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    Picasso.get().load(item.imageUrl).into(holder.imageView)

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("iImages", item.imageUrl)
        context.startActivity(intent)

    }
}

class ViewHolder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val imageView : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)

}
```

}

**DetailsActivity**

```
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)


    val aImageView = intent.getIntExtra("iImages", 0)
    details_image.setImageResource(aImageView)
}
```

}

**RecyclerActivity**

```
class RecyclerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler)

    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val storageRef = storage.reference.child("wallpapers")
    val imageList : ArrayList<Item> = ArrayList()
    //progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val listAllTask : Task<ListResult> = storageRef.listAll()
    listAllTask.addOnCompleteListener { result ->
        val items: List<StorageReference> = result.result!!.items

        //add cycle for add image url to list
        items.forEachIndexed { index,item ->
            item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("item", "$it")
                imageList.add(Item(it.toString()))
            }.addOnCompleteListener {
                recyclerview.adapter = ImageAdapter(imageList, this)
                recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
                //progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

**Item**
data class Item(
var imageUrl: String
)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
details_image.setImageResource(aImageView)
```

You are setting a resource int but what you pass seems to be a url, so instead load the "iImages" value with Picasso for that view

Edit: Replace this:

```
val aImageView = intent.getIntExtra("iImages", 0)
details_image.setImageResource(aImageView)
```

with this

```
val retrievedImageUrl = intent.getIntExtra("iImages", 0)
Picasso.get().load(retrievedImageUrl).into(details_image)
```

Comment: @Elrik I edited my answer, tell me if that solves it

Comment: Thx a lot friend

Comment: @Elrik Glad I could help, if you can mark the answer as the solution please

Answer (score 0):

The Answer

```
val imageView : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.details_image)
    Glide.with(this).load(intent.getStringExtra("iImages")).into(imageView)
```

Comment: Be more specific!